# C++ - Function always returns true

Tags: c++

My C++ function always returns true. Always. Even if I change the return value to 'false' it still returns true. I would laugh but I've kinda gone past that to the stage where it just doesn't make sense to me AT ALL.

(In case anyone's interested, the code is for [Conway's Game Of Life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life))

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>


bool getCellStates(bool cells[16][16], int i, int j)
{
    int alive = 0;
    bool isAlive;

    if(cells[i][j-1] && j-1 >= 0)
        alive++;
    if(cells[i+1][j-1] && i+1 <= 15 && j-1 >= 0)
        alive++;
    if(cells[i+1][j] && i+1 <= 15)
        alive++;
    if(cells[i+1][j+1] && i+1 <=15 && j+1 <= 15)
        alive++;
    if(cells[i][j+1] && j+1 <= 15)
        alive++;
    if(cells[i-1][j+1] && i-1 >= 0 && j+1 <=15)
        alive++;
    if(cells[i-1][j] && i-1 >= 0)
        alive++;
    if(cells[i-1][j-1]&& i-1 >=0 && j-1 >= 0)
        alive++;

    if(alive == 3)
        isAlive = true;
    else if(cells[i][j] && alive == 2)
        isAlive = true;
    else
        isAlive = false;

    return isAlive;    // Also returns true if I change to 'return false;'
}


int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(640, 480), "Game Of Life");

    bool cells[16][16];
    int i, j = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 16; j++)
        {
            cells[i][j] = false;
            std::cout << i << ", " << j << ": " << cells[i][j] << std::endl;
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < 16; i ++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 16; j++)
        {
            cells[i][j] = getCellStates[cells, i, j];
            std::cout << i << ", " << j << ": " << cells[i][j] << std::endl;
        }
    }


    while(window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while(window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if(event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: does this line even compile? `cells[i][j] = getCellStates[cells, i, j];`

Comment: If you had tried using a debugger in the first place, you would not have needed to post this question (as thou would see that your function is never getting called… though you may have had to post a different question to ask why that was). Please do not use stackoverflow as your _first_ line of defense.

Comment: My apologies, it's just my debugger is kinda dodgy... I'm still learning how to use it. Also don't patronise me - I know not to just ask a question before investigating it first. I hate it when arrogant people assume everyone else is stupid. Also, yes it does compile.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem lies not within the function, but at the call site (for as far as it is a call site). Use parentheses to call a function, not brackets.

```
cells[i][j] = getCellStates(cells, i, j);
```

You are converting a function pointer to a Boolean, which is indeed always `true`. Subscripting of function pointers is a non-standard extension, so enable compiler warnings and pedantry to prevent this kind of errors. For GCC and clang I recommend the following flags:

```
-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic
```

Comment: Another victim of some wild non-standard GCC extension. Apparently GCC allows pointer arithmetic on function pointers... Ridiculous.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And although I do not know what your comment means AndreyT I AM using GCC so... I blame the compiler ;)